# webflow testing, unable to find flow model

Tags: java, spring, spring-webflow

I have this very annoying problem I cannot figure out.

This is the main structure of my webflow project:

- WEB-INF/flows/basic/basic-flow.xml
- WEB-INF/flows/error/error-flow.xml

The error flow contains common exception handling and is abstract. Basic flow has the error flow as parent.

When I try to write a JUnit test I get into a problem where it is not able to load the error flow. I have tested basic by itself (just removing the parent attribute) and it works just fine. Any advice to what I could be doing wrong?

Here are the important parts of the test code:

```
@Override
protected FlowDefinitionResource getResource(FlowDefinitionResourceFactory resourceFactory) {
    return resourceFactory.createFileResource("src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/flows/basic/basic-flow.xml");
}

@Override
protected FlowDefinitionResource[] getModelResources(FlowDefinitionResourceFactory resourceFactory) {
    FlowDefinitionResource flowDefinitionResource = resourceFactory
            .createFileResource("src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/flows/error/error-flow.xml");

    return new FlowDefinitionResource[] { flowDefinitionResource };
}

public void testStartBasicFlow() {
    MockExternalContext context = new MockExternalContext();
    startFlow(context);
}
```

The exception I get is this:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.webflow.engine.model.registry.NoSuchFlowModelException: No flow model 'error' found
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Your `error` flow You should probably explicitelly pass a `flowId`:

```
FlowDefinitionResource flowDefinitionResource = resourceFactory.createResource(
    "src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/flows/error/error-flow.xml", null, "error");
```

When using `FlowDefinitionResource.createFileResource(..)` the `flowId` is the result of the `FlowDefinitionResource.getFlowId(..)`, wich may not evaluate to `error` in Your case.