# Spring Webflow 2.3 Testing (with Maven): How to reference parent flow with filename different from id

Tags: eclipse, maven, classpath, spring-webflow

I debugged my Spring Webflow test to the point of figuring out the first part of the issue: When you have a flow with a filename that is not the same as the id of the flow ('commons-flow.xml' with id='commons') then just using resourceFactory.createFileResource(pathToFlowFile) does not work because that assumes the id is the filename.

There is a method available to override the id, `resourceFactory.createResource(pathToFlowFile, attributesMap, overrideId)`

However, this uses the Classloader to resolves files whereas it seems the createFileResource used a different means.

I cannot figure out how I am supposed to get the Classloader to recognize the flow files. I inspected it's classpaths and it only has the JAR dependencies and then dynamically created target/classes and target/test-classes folders. No reference to my project.

This is a Maven project, and the path I have from project root to flows is something like:

```
src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/flows/<flow-folder>/<flow-filename>.xml
```

I have seen [webflow testing, unable to find flow model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6422748/webflow-testing-unable-to-find-flow-model) which reiterates what I discovered already, but for some reason I have the issue with the Classloader that other seems not to have.

Where I see people successfully referencing the flow files, they seem to either be relative from the project root or relative from the WebContext at src/main/webapp.

I am running the JUnit test with a Run Configuration in Eclipse and also with the maven test goal.

It is possible for me to configure a custom classpath for the Run Configuration in Eclipse to include the parent folder of the relative path I have defined as pathToFlowFile.

However, that does not help at all with Maven, which has the classloader/classpath issue still when executing the test goal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ran into something similar where I had to set the flow id and specify the path. So instead of using the FlowDefinitionResourceFactory I created a FlowDefinitionResource instance like below

```
FlowDefinitionResource resource = new FlowDefinitionResource(flowId, path, attributes);
```

So in your method you should have something like this

```
protected FlowDefinitionResource[] getModelResources(FlowDefinitionResourceFactory resourceFactory) {
    FlowDefinitionResource resource = new FlowDefinitionResource("flowId", src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/flows/<flow-folder>/<flow-filename>.xml", null);
    return new FlowDefinitionResource[] {resource};
}
```

If you get a FileNotFoundException just check the stacktrace to see where it is looking for the file.

Hope this helps.

M

Comment: Hey, I think the answer is incomplete, the constructor for FlowDefinitionResource is (String, org.springframework.core.io.Resource, AttributeMap) not (String, String, AttributeMap)

Comment: @rich this was the constructor I found on webflow version 2.3.0 and spring 3.0.5.release so maybe it's been updated. Also I forgot to add initiative is required :)

Comment: Sure. I did find the way to construct the Resource object as a FileSystemResource. I thought I edited the answer yesterday with it, but I don't see that it took. Will reaccept when the edit takes place.

Comment: no worries rich. The documentation on webflow is a nightmare esp on testing the flows I've wasted so much time trawling through the source.

Comment: Edit is not being accepted, so as a comment, the references to path in the answer above needed to be replaced with new FileSystemResource(path) when using the version of Spring WebFlow I am using.